# Dropdownlist bounded to list doesn't return right value nor select right item

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I've built an interface in which i bind a `List<TripStop>` objects to it and ask the dropdown list to use:

```
//Convert the TripStop dictionnary to a list for databinding
StartStop.DataSource = EditorPlugin.getTripStops().Values.ToList();
StartStop.ValueMember = "Id";
StartStop.DisplayMember = "NameFr";
```

Id and NameFr as Value/DisplayMembers.

If i inspect the datasource after binding it, i see all my data bounded correctly, each property of each object is fine, my data is not corrupted.

Problem? If i select something and look at the SelectedValue, i get the wrong value out, i get the "Id" of a completely different item.

Reverse is the same, i load the form and ask the DropDownList to :

```
StartStop.SelectedValue = EditorObject.StartStop;
```

And what i am shown is a completely different item from the real value i asked it to select. For example, i ask for item #4 and i get #14 selected. I select item #4 in the list and the SelectedValue is #14.

There are not correlation between index and value.

Stranger yet, if i do:

```
EditorObject.StartStop = (UInt32)((TripStop)StartStop.SelectedItem).Id;
```

This method works fine and i get the correct value out of the selecteditem.

Comment: Double check that you don't have anything thing DataBound to the Text field of the combobox. When dragging a datasource and creating the combobox it sets this by default and is easy to miss when setting your actual data binding. This sort of odd behavior is reminiscent of what saw when this extra binding was present.

Comment: Dragging a datasource? Explain what you mean? I just dragdropped a a dropdownlist, named it and then i coded the rest...

Comment: You can disregard my comment then. If you have DB or object data sources in the DataSource window you can set a property's default control type then drag and drop it on to a form and have it's databinding created for you. It works quite well for most everything but for a combobox the behavior sets the data binding from the source data to the Text property of the combobox (instead of the SelectedValue) and of course you still have to wire up the ValueMember and DisplayMember to the data for filling the combobox.

Comment: Thank you for that information, i don't use databinding like that but it's very interresting information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance checking the value of your selections in SelectedIndexChanged or SelectedValueChanged? I had some issues with that because programmitcal assignment vs. user selected assignment so switched to SelectionChangeCommitted. Here is an example that I know works...

```
// On Load...
city_IDComboBox.DataSource = context.Cities.Local.ToBindingList();
city_IDComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
city_IDComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";

// Checking value of selection, acting on it
private void city_IDComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var currentCounty = county_IDComboBox.SelectedItem as County;
   var currentCity = city_IDComboBox.SelectedItem as City;
   if (currentCity != null)
   {
      if (currentCounty != null)
      {
         if (currentCity.County_ID == currentCounty.ID)
            return;
      }
      county_IDComboBox.SelectedValue = currentCity.County_ID;
   }
   else
   {
      county_IDComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Nope, i'm using SelectedIndexChanged to detect a change and i enable a button to save the form then in the form's save button handler i check the value and it's not right, there would have been millions of milliseconds to commit the change to memory inbetween :)